# How to set autofit for Excel columns in Mule

Tags: dataweave, mule4

I need help where need to do the proper alignment in the send email attachment (the attachment should be an Excel sheet).

Does anyone have an idea to set autofit in the Excel columns in Mule?

Answer (score 0):

The question is really unrelated to how the Excel file is used. In this case you want to send it through email but it doesn't matter. If instead the Excel document would be transferred by SFTP or HTTP it would not be modified. The question should be about how to generate an Excel output with the desired properties irrespective of how you use it later.

The short answer is that it is not supported. The long answer is that [DataWeave](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave), the expression and transformation language of Mule 4, supports [generating Excel](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-formats-excel#example2) only supports the data contents in Excel table and not formatting.